# how to read csv file without specific number of column in java and without change the code after every additional column

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, arrayobject

I tried to write code to read csv file, and I stored the data in an array of object
but after every change in the number of columns, I  should read another column and change the code.
because I want to use the same class for different csv files with different number of columns without need to change the code for every file.

```
    public class Read_CSV {
        public static Object[][]readCSVdata(String csvFilePath){
     //String csvFilePath = null;
     ArrayList<Object[]>dataList = new ArrayList <Object[]>();
        String line = "";
          String cvsSplitBy = ",";
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath))) {

        int iteration = 0;
        
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(iteration == 0) {
                iteration++;  
                continue;
            }
            String[] arri = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
            Object[]arri1= {arri[0] , arri[1],arri[2] };
              //here after every additional column I should add another cell
            dataList.add(arri1);
        }      
        br.close();
        return dataList.toArray(new Object[dataList.size()][]);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the array of strings after splitting each line:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(iteration == 0) {
        iteration++;  
        continue;
    }
    String[] arri = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    
    dataList.add(arri);
}
```

Then `dataList` will contain arrays of strings.

Or you have some other requirements?